# WCF service with platform as x86 not working on 64 bit server

Tags: wcf, x86, hosting

I have createda WCF service with platform as x86 in visual studio and deployed it on 32 bit windows server.
Its works fine.

But when I depl0yed same WCF service(Published) on 64 bit server its giving me one of the dependency failed to load.

Please help me on this..

TIAWCF

Comment: Please post more information on what dependency failed to load or error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to register the DLL which failed to load (on the 64bit server) with - regsvr32 dllname.dll.